# Generalize spinor bundles over orthogonal Grassmannians

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, quadratic-forms, grassmannians

We will work over $\mathbb C$ and the notation will be coherent with the paper of Ottaviani (see [[Ott]](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1988-307-01/S0002-9947-1988-0936818-5/S0002-9947-1988-0936818-5.pdf)).

Consider a $n$-dimensional quadric hypersurface $Q_n \subset \mathbb P^{n+1}$. We have embeddings of the quadric in a Grassmannian, according to the parity of $n$:
$$
s:Q_{2k+1} \hookrightarrow G\left(\mathbb P^{2^k-1}, \mathbb P^{2^{k+1}-1}\right)=G\left(2^k,2^{k+1}\right),
$$
$$
s':Q_{2k} \hookrightarrow G\left(\mathbb P^{2^{k-1}-1},\mathbb P^{2^k-1} \right)=G\left(2^{k-1},2^k\right), \qquad s'':Q_{2k} \hookrightarrow G\left(\mathbb P^{2^{k-1}-1},\mathbb P^{2^k-1} \right)=G\left(2^{k-1},2^k\right).
$$
Let $U$ be the universal bundle over the Grassmannian, fitting in the short exact sequence
$$
0 \to U \to V \otimes \mathcal O \to Q \to 0.
$$
We define the *spinor bundle* over $Q_{2k+1}$ as $S=s^* U$, its rank is $2^k$. On the other hand, we call the *spinor bundles* over $Q_{2k}$ to be $S'=(s')^* U$ and $S''=(s'')^* U$, both of rank $2^{k-1}$. If $f: Q_{2k} \to Q_{2k}$ is an automorphism exchanging the two families of $\mathbb P^k$, then $f^* S' \simeq S''$ and $f^* S'' \simeq S'$.

Moreover, one can prove that these vector bundles are homogeneous ones.

In Section 2 of [[Ott]](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1988-307-01/S0002-9947-1988-0936818-5/S0002-9947-1988-0936818-5.pdf), we have the following result (Theorem 2.8):

**Theorem.**

1. Consider the spinor bundle $S \to Q_{2k+1}$. Then there is a short exact sequence
   $$
   0 \to S \to \mathcal O^{\oplus 2^{k+1}} \to S(1) \to 0
   $$
   and $S^\vee \simeq S(1)$.
2. Consider the spinor bundles $S',S'' \to Q_{2k}$. Then there are two short exact sequences
   $$
   0 \to S' \to \mathcal O^{2^k} \to S''(1) \to 0, \qquad 0 \to S'' \to \mathcal O^{2^k} \to S'(1) \to 0.
   $$
   If $k \equiv 0 \pmod 2 $, we have $(S')^\vee \simeq S'(1)$ and $(S'')^\vee \simeq S''(1)$. Otherwise, if $k \equiv 1 \pmod 2$, we have $(S')^\vee \simeq S''(1)$ and $(S'')^\vee \simeq S'(1)$.

**Finally the question.** Consider the orthogonal Grassmannian $OG(m+1,n+2)$, which parametrize $\mathbb P^m \subset Q_n$ (note that $Q_n$ is obtained by $m=0$). Can we generalize the construction of spinor bundles to some bundles over $OG(m+1,n+2)$? In particular, is there an embedding of $OG(m+1,n+2)$ into a Grassmannian $G$ like $s,s',s''$?

At this point, one defines the spinor bundles over $OG(m+1,n+2)$ as the pullback of the universal bundle over the Grassmannian $G$ and the rank is clear.

**Second question.** Having defined the spinor bundles over the orthogonal Grassmannians, can we produce some short exact sequences like the ones in the theorem above?

Comment: See Section 6 in [Kuznetsov, Alexander Exceptional collections for Grassmannians of isotropic lines. Proc. Lond. Math. Soc. (3) 97 (2008), no. 1, 155–182].

Comment: @Sasha: that's a perfect reference, thanks! Just a more question, if you can reply to me. In the paper that you cite, one can define the (generalized) spinor bundle starting from the $\mathcal O(1)$ of one of the two spinor variety, let's say $\mathfrak F^+_m$ (I am now using the notation contained in the paper). However, the definition of spinor bundle is not given for $\mathfrak F^-_m$, can one generalize the incidence construction a little more to include this case?

Comment: $$ \mathfrak F^-_m \longleftarrow \mathfrak F^\pm_m \longrightarrow \mathfrak F^+_m$$ and one define the spinor bundle to be $(\pi_-)_*(\pi_+)^* \mathcal O(1)$? What is its rank?

Comment: I can compute such a bundle using a different technique ($\mathbb C^*$-actions, smooth drums...), but I want to understand if such a definition of (generalized) spinor bundle can be extended in this direction

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the question. What is the variety in the middle of your diagram. What are the maps $\pi_\pm$? What are smooth drums?

Comment: Sorry, $\mathfrak F^\pm_m$ is $\operatorname{OGr}(m,V)$ and $\pi_\pm: \operatorname{OGr}(m,V) \to \mathfrak F^\pm_m$ arę the projection to the two factors

Comment: For the definition of smooth drum, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.12129.pdf, Section 4

Comment: If $\dim(V) = 2m$ (which you probably assume) then $\mathrm{OGr}(m,V)$ has two connected components, not two factors.

Comment: Yes, sorry for pointing out the typo: $\operatorname{OGr}(m-1,V)$

Comment: The map $\pi_+$ is a $\mathbb{P}^{m-1}$ fibration, and the line bundle $\pi_-^*\mathcal{O}(1)$ is its linear hyperplane class, therefore its pushforward has rank $m$. In fact, this is the equivariant vector bundle associated with the fundamental weight $\omega_{m-1}$ (if we assume that $\mathfrak{F}_m^+$ is associated with the vertex $m$).